# Importing Excel File Through php and i always get an error of undefined offset

Tags: php

Here is my exact code and im always getting an error of Undefined offset in my array

```
<?php 
require_once('../../../Backend/Listings_Database/Listings_Connection.php');

$Response = array();

if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {   
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    $file = fopen($filename, "r"); 
    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        (name,brand,cat_id,
         store_size,location_floor_unit,phone,traffic_of_mall,
         time_of_traffic,city) 
        values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]',
               '$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]',
               '$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]','$emapData[8]')"; 

        //we are using mysql_query function. it returns a resource on true else False on error 

        $result = mysqli_query($sql,$Listings_Database);

        if(! $result ) { 
            $Response[] = "Fail"; 
        } else { 
            $Response[] = "Success";
        }
    } 
    fclose($file);

    $Response[] = "Success";

    mysqli_close($Listings_Database);  
} else {
    $Response[] = "Fail";
}

var_dump($Response);

print json_encode($Response);

?>
```

Here is my exact code and im always getting an error of Undefined offset in my array

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You never actually load your query into `$Listings_Database` HUGE TYPO

Comment: Your query is also a complete syntactical nonsense

Comment: Also that error message also contains a line number. _Please always include the COMPLETE error message and indicate which line in your code sample is the line with the error_

Comment: What is `$sql` and what is `$Listings_Database` I dont see anywhere where either are being set

Comment: You have **8** column names and **9** values in the `value(...)` clause. **Lay out your code in a readable way and these minor errors will become obvious**

Comment: You do not have an `INSERT` in your query

Comment: You do not set the query you write into a variable! I assume it should be `$Listings_Database = "INSERT INTO <tablename> .........`

Comment: Thanks guys , i already resolve it.. but now my problem is.. the special characters is not inserting correctly

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Which line shows this "getting an error of Undefined offset" error.
Also take this approach:

```
 $name = !empty($emapData[0]) ? $emapData[0] : '';
 $brand = !empty($emapData[1]) ? $emapData[1] : '';
```

and so on...
 And then use in your query:

`insert into <tableName>
(name,brand,cat_id,store_size,location_floor_unit,phone,traffic_of_mall,time_of_traffic,city) values('$name','$brand',......)";`

Comment: Let me know the cause of downvote

Comment: thanks ill try this

Comment: Now im getting special characters in inserting

Comment: Echo your insert query, so It will easy to find out the error. Also update your code, so We can help you.